# XAML List/ItemView Background 'Drawing'

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

within WPF I have created a ListView which displays a list of messages in chronological order using a custom ItemsPanel class which uses the time of the messages to correct space them apart when laying out the items;

[image]

Is there an easy way to go one step further and add 'other drawing items', for example a timeline (line, ticks and text), to the background of the ListView which scrolls with it? What's the best approach?

Comment: I think you should elaborate on what your custom itemspanel is. Kind of the obvious way to put things in a listview is to put em in a listview item by templating data into paths or drawings or the like. Is that an acceptable route to go and if not, why not?

Comment: Absolutely you can. Your items are just displayed via an `ItemsPresenter` that sits inside a ScrollViewer, but the question would be more specific to what you expect the output to look like, if it's based around the item itself, those types elements may be better suited for your actual item template as opposed to the panel hosting them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments, but my solution was to add an ItemsControl which binds to a Timeline collection of integers (one every 100ms) that's sits on top of the ListView (and scrolls with it) which simply has two lines it the ItemTemplate to get the following result:

[ListView with added timeline markings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPlHg.png)